# Bugs in C Switch Menu using a Char as Choice, Won't Read in fgets name

Tags: c, binary

> Im basically Writing a program that creates, reads, updates and
>   deletes records in a binary file.
>
> Everything compiles correctly, no syntax errors, but I do have some
>   bugs.

**KNOWN BUGS**

> 1.) Imputing any strings does not work, using fgets
>
> 2.) Ctrl-D Does Work but outputs a 'default' error before it exits.
>
> 3.) Update does not work (Not my main issue at the moment as the others are more important for now.)
>
> 4?) I'm not sure if the menu is working how it's supposed to work. I
>   think the do while is correct, since in the menu if I select and hit
>   CTRL-D it does exit the program. Just wanna be sure.
>
> Right now I just want to know why, It is skipping the courseName in
>   the inputs function.

**Here is my code thus far**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>    
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef  struct{
char  courseName [64];
char  courseSched [4];
unsigned  int  courseHours;
unsigned  int  courseSize;} COURSE;

FILE *pfileCourse;
int courseNumber = 0;

//Prototypes

void inputDetails(COURSE *c);
void readCourseRecord();
void createCourseRecord();
void print_menu();
void modifyCourseInfo();
void deleteCourse();
void display(COURSE c);


/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char choice;    // this is the choice
printf("Enter one of the following actions or press CTRL-D to exit\n");
printf("C - Create a new course record\n");
printf("R - Read an existing course record\n");
printf("U - Update an existing course record\n");
printf("D - Delete an existing course record\n");

do{
    choice = getchar();
    switch(choice) {
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
        printf("YOU PICKED C for Create\n");
        createCourseRecord();
        break;
        case 'r':
        case 'R':
        printf("This is Choice R\n");
        readCourseRecord();
        break;
        case 'u':
        case 'U':
        printf("Here is where you update an existing course\n");
        modifyCourseInfo();
        break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D':
        printf("here is where you Delete an existing course record\n");
        deleteCourse();
        break;
        default:
        printf("Wrong Choice!\n");
} 

}while(choice != EOF);
return 0;
}

void createCourseRecord() {
COURSE data;
pfileCourse = fopen("courses.dat", "ab");
printf("Please Enter The Details of The Course\n");
inputDetails(&data);
fwrite(&data, sizeof(data), 1, pfileCourse);
fclose(pfileCourse);
printf("Course Has Been Created!\n");
}


void inputDetails(COURSE *c) {

printf("Enter a course number: \n");
scanf("%d", &courseNumber);

printf("Enter a Course Name: \n");
fgets(c->courseName, sizeof(courseName), stdin);

printf("Enter the course schedule (MWF or TR): \n");
fgets(c->courseSched, 4, stdin);
fflush(stdin);

printf("Enter the course credit hours: \n");
scanf("%d",&c->courseHours);
fflush(stdin);

printf("Enter Number of Students Enrolled: \n");
scanf("%d",&c->courseSize);
return;
}

void readCourseRecord(){
COURSE data;
int flag = 0;
int readCourseNumber = 0;
printf("Please Enter a Course Number to Display\n");
scanf("%d", &readCourseNumber);
fflush(stdin);

pfileCourse = fopen("courses.dat", "rb");
while((fread(&data, sizeof(data), 1, pfileCourse)) > 0) {
    if(readCourseNumber == courseNumber)
    {
        display(data);
        flag = 1;
    }
}
fclose(pfileCourse);
if(flag == 0)
    printf("Course not Found!\n");
}

void deleteCourse(){
int newCourseNum;
COURSE data;
FILE *file2;

printf("Please Enter The Course You Wish You Delete\n");
scanf("%d", &newCourseNum);
pfileCourse = fopen("courses.dat", "rb");
file2 = fopen("temp.dat", "wb");
rewind(pfileCourse);
while((fread(&data, sizeof(data), 1, pfileCourse)) > 0)
{
    if(courseNumber != newCourseNum)
    {
        fwrite(&data, sizeof(data), 1, file2);
    }
}
fclose(file2);
fclose(pfileCourse);
remove("courses.dat");
rename("temp.dat", "courses.dat");
printf("%d was Successfully deleted\n", newCourseNum);
}

void modifyCourseInfo()
{
COURSE data;
int newCourseNum, found = 0;

printf("Modify\n");
printf("Please Enter The Course You Wish You Modify\n");
scanf("%d", &newCourseNum);

pfileCourse = fopen("courses.dat", "rb+");
while ((fread(&data, sizeof(data), 1, pfileCourse)) > 0 && found == 0)
{
    if (courseNumber == newCourseNum)
    {
        display(data);
        printf("Please Enter New Details\n");
        inputDetails(&data);
        fseek(pfileCourse, - (long)sizeof(data), 1);
        fwrite(&data, sizeof(data), 1, pfileCourse);
        printf("Course Updated\n");
        found == 1;

    }
}
fclose(pfileCourse);
if(found == 0)
        printf("ERROR: course not found\n");
}

void display(COURSE c){
printf("courseNumber:\t %d\n", courseNumber);
printf("courseName:\t %s\n",c.courseName);
printf("courseSched:\t %s\n",c.courseSched);
printf("courseName:\t %d\n",c.courseHours);
printf("courseSize:\t %d\n",c.courseSize);
}
```

Comment: I didn't analyze your codee, but don't mix scanf and fgets. In fact you never should use scanf for interactive input. Use fgets and scan the string with sscanf.

Comment: okay so if i were to remove the scanf, i should use fgets right?

and for the strings use sscanf?

well for the int i am using fgets and i get this error for the courseNumber

warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't skip courseName, courseName just gets value '\n' because scanf function stops reading your input BEFORE white space. [Scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) ignores any whitespace characters encountered before the next non-whitespace character. So you can just add

```
scanf("%d[^\n]", &courseNumber);
getchar();
```

after every scanf you have but I'd recommend you to use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/?kw=fgets) function for every interactive input.

Comment: i'm trying to figure out how to use fgets, in fact aren't i using fgets in my code?
but alright let me change that up and see what it does

Comment: in this case the input is a int, i keep getting this error when i switch it to fgets
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘fgets’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`: consider this as an error and read the documentaton of `fgets`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky it's because I'm passing an int instead of a char, which is why i'm not getting it in the other fgets statements

its the "buffer" so to say right?

Comment: read the docs of fgets, use google, i'm on a phone now, and I cannot write much. good luck